# Extract data from .txt or .dat file and importing data to oracle table in Python 3

Tags: python

I want to extract data from .txt or .dat file in Oracle table in Python 3.

Below are file rows(No column header)

```
BASIC   INCSTMT 1   2   EXP N/A GROUP   N/A N/A N/A N   N   NULL    LDGR{100-100,190-300,500-700}
BASIC   INCSTMT 1   3   NET N/A QUERY   N/A N/A N/A N   N   NULL    ABC+XYZ
BASIC   INCSTMT 1   4   ALL N/A QUERY   N/A N/A N/A N   N   NULL    AAA-BBB-CCC
```

I want these values in separate variable and rearrange and insert in table as 2-3 columns need to shuffle.
For last value which is

```
1. LDGR{1001-1002,190-300,500-700}
2. ABC+XYZ
3. AAA-BBB-CCC
```

I want to store these values to like var1 = 1001, var2 = 1002, var1 = 190, var2 = 300.
So, I can insert these value in Begin_ldgr and End_ldgr.

I tried with below code but getting error as IndexError: list index out of range.

```py
import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_csv("D:\PythonProjects\ldgritem_bbh.dat", header=None)
    ldgr_acct = df.iloc[:,13]

    var1_values = []
    var2_values = []

    for entry in ldgr_acct:
        ranges = entry.split('{')[1].split('}')[0].split(',')
        for i, range_value in enumerate(ranges):
            if range_value:
                var1, var2 = map(int, range_value.split('-'))
                if i % 2 == 0:
                    var1_values.append(var1)
                    var2_values.append(var2)
                else:
                    var1_values.append(var1)
                    var2_values.append(var2)

    for var1, var2 in zip(var1_values, var2_values):
        print(f"var1 = {var1}, var2 = {var2}")
```